# Returning true if you can split a list into smaller list with minimum two values in the parted list else return false

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging, stack, logic

In a deck of cards, each card has an integer written on it.

Return true if and only if it is possible to split the entire deck into 1 or more groups of cards, where:

Each group has at least 2 cards.
All the cards in each group have the same integer.

**Example:**

Input: deck = `[1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1]`

Output: true

Explanation: Possible partition `[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]`.

I tried solving this using stack but it is not working as expected and it is printing false where it is supposed to print true. I have added comment for clarity of my code.

package practicepkg;

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class DeckInteger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        //declaring individual variable for each integer and setting all of them to zero
        int p_1=0,p_2=0,p_3=0,p_4=0,p_5=0,p_6=0,p_7=0,p_8=0,p_9=0;
        
        //adding element which can form pair and should return true
        stack.add(1);
        stack.add(2);
        stack.add(1);
        stack.add(2);
        stack.add(1);
        stack.add(2);
        
        
        //checking till stack is empty and comparing the top of stack to all the individual integer and incrementing them and popping the top element 
        while(stack.empty()==false) {
            if(stack.peek()==1) {
                p_1+=1;
                stack.pop();                        
                break;
            } else if(stack.peek()==2) {
                p_2+=1;
                stack.pop();                        
                break;
            } else if(stack.peek()==3) {
                stack.pop();
                p_3+=1;
                break;
            } else if(stack.peek()==4) {
                stack.pop();
                p_4+=1;
                break;
            } else if(stack.peek()==5) {
                stack.pop();
                p_5+=1;
                break;
            } else if(stack.peek()==6) {
                stack.pop();
                p_6+=1;
                break;
            } else if(stack.peek()==7) {
                stack.pop();
                p_7+=1;
                break;
            } else if(stack.peek()==8) {
                stack.pop();
                p_8+=1;
                break;
            } else {
                stack.pop();
                p_9+=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        //checking if any of the integer variable have the value 1 then it cannot form pair as x>=2 so it should print false
        if(p_1==1||p_2==1||p_3==1||p_4==1||p_5==1||p_6==1||p_7==1||p_8==1||p_9==1) {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
        //print true as if any of the variable have a value other than one
        else {
            System.out.println("True");
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `a_i` cards with integer `i`, then all possible partitions would be divisors of `a_i`, otherwise, this card can't be split. Therefore you only need to count up all the unique numbers and calculate their greatest common divisor. This greatest common divisor would be the largest possible X.

Comment: hey , can you tell me why my code is not working?

Comment: Your code is not working because you have a break in your code, it breaks while loop, and you only count the last number from your input, not all of them. Suppose it is left after transitioning from the switch case. Anyway, it is unimportant, because it would still be incorrect after the fix. For example, if you have numbers [2, 2, 3, 3, 3] as your input, your code (after fix) will return true, while there is no partition of such input.

Comment: If I remove break , we can create partition of [2,2] and [3,3,3] btw I only need need to check for variable to have value other than one.

Comment: for the love of God , a big thankyou to you. It solved my issue. You are best. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are using `break` inside each `if` condition. So it would break out of the `while` loop in the first iteration itself. So only `p_1` would be equal to `1` and all others would be `0`.
There is a much better way to solve this using `Maps` with key as the integer and value as it's count

Assuming the input as an array : `int[] input`

```
private boolean isValidGroup(Stack<Integer> stack){
    Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();   
    while(!stack.empty()){
        countMap.merge(stack.pop(),1,Integer::sum);
    }
    // The above map would contain the count for each integer.
    // For input : {1,2,4,2,4,3,1,3} , the map would be {1:2,2:2,3:2,4:2}
    
    List<Integer> distinctCounts = countMap.values().stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    // The above list contains the distinct group counts.

    // Ideally the number of distinct count value should be 1 and the value should be >=2.
    //In such case, we return true.
    return (distinctCounts.size()==1 && distinctCounts.get(0)>=2);
}
```

Comment: hey thankyou for your solution. it look much more elegant though I was asked to solve it using stack only.

Comment: Even in that case, `Map` could be used instead of 10 different integer variables. Also with the map you could have used a single `if` condition inside the `while` loop

Comment: @BiggestNoob, I have updated the answer using `Stack`